# Criar uma resposta para uma pergunta resolvida, porém sem resposta

Tags: debate

Parece confuso o título, mas olhando o link abaixo vocês entenderão:

[Verificar se há itens visíveis dentro de uma div](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72959/verificar-se-h%C3%A1-itens-vis%C3%ADveis-dentro-de-uma-div)

Eu não sabia que era permitido fazer isso. Tipo, pegar uma pergunta resolvida, porém sem resposta. Normalmente o AP resolve lendo os comentários e não dá um feedback apropriado.

Então, é possível? É legal dentro dos termos da comunidade Stack Overflow?

Creio que seja permitido, pois quem respondeu foi um membro com "alta" reputação e muito ativo.

Apenas para esclarecer, talvez alguém interprete como crítica e tal, mas realmente não tem nada a ver. Apenas fiquei curioso em saber sobre isso.

Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Relacionado: [Por que muitas pessoas respondem nos comentários em vez de criar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2333/3117)

Comment: valeu pelo link! entendi!

Comment: Então Daniel eu solicitei uma vez pra ele formular a resposta, mas como ele não entendeu, então formulei a resposta e comentei pra ele formular (copiar a minha) e assim que ele o fizesse eu iria deletar http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72959/verificar-se-há-itens-visíveis-dentro-de-uma-div#comment149536_72959 , pois eu retirei/recortei a resposta do "corpo" da pergunta, isto foi apenas para a resposta ficar salva. No entanto ele preferiu me dar o crédito, o motivo eu realmente não sei. Eu preferiria que ele mesmo responde-se, a minha ideia foi deixar a resposta disponível para os outros.

Comment: Outra coisa, também é que notei que as pessoas não entendem o funcionamento da comunidade, eu as vezes insisto 4 vezes orientando os autores, mas eles não entendem e ficam mais confusos ainda. Pois eles pensam que isto se trata de uma fórum (geralmente), então eu prefiro ir pelo "mostrar" o caminho correto com comentários e ações. Se o autor postar a resposta, então apago a que eu fiz de exemplo. Veja está situação: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28784/3635 o autor não postou uma resposta, apenas um link, então postei uma resposta de "exemplo" :)

Comment: imaginei isso mesmo, Guilherme. Obrigado por detalhar!

Comment: Conforme a dica do @bigown - agora a resposta é um wiki da comunidade.

Answer (score 7):

Não tem problema, o importante é ter uma resposta. Claro que se a resposta não é algo que você sabe responder, criando algo autoral, se for algo que foi dado por outra pessoa e você está apenas reproduzindo para ter uma resposta, aí é de bom tom deixar a resposta como Community Wiki, assim abrindo mão da autoria.

Comment: valeu!! Eu não sabia o que era wiki community. Agora entendo como usar. Pesquisei aqui mesmo e encontrei tópicos como esse: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1667/incluir-link-sobre-community-wiki